# laravel controller not matching database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

First apologies for the title, I couldn't think of a better description.
I have a controller that is suppose to read a database then return it as an object.  This database recently went through a change in structure, and I re-seeded it.  My controller code is:

```php
$books = \App\book::where('userId',1)->get();
foreach ($books as $b) {
    echo$b->bookId;
}
```

This will result in the following out output:

> 70008000

.
However, if I run the same through tinker I get an entirely different result.  Tinker code: `App\Book::where('userId',1)->get();`
will result in several records such as:

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3018
>        all: [
>          App\book {#2996
>            recordId: 1,
>            **bookId: "7iraCwAAQBAJ"**,
>            userId: 1,
>            authorId: 1,
>            title: "The Witch of Lime Street",
>            isbn: "9780307451064",
>            description: "In 1924 the wife of a Boston surgeon came to embody the raging national debate over Spiritualism, a movement
>   devoted to communication with the dead. Reporters dubbed her the
>   blonde Witch of Lime Street, but she was known to her followers simply
>   as Margery. Her most vocal advocate was Sir Arthur Conan Doyle, who
>   believed so thoroughly in Margery's powers that he urged her to enter
>   a controversial contest, sponsored by Scientific American. Her
>   supernatural gifts beguiled four of the judges. There was only one
>   left to convince ... the acclaimed escape artist, Harry Houdini. Jaher
>   captures their electric public rivalry and the competition that
>   brought them into each other's orbit.",
>            preview: "http://books.google.com/books?id=7iraCwAAQBAJ&dq=9780307451071&hl=&source=gbs_api",
>            cover: "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=7iraCwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
>            book_status: "reading",
>            created_at: "2019-08-16 12:30:27",
>            updated_at: "2019-08-16 12:30:27",
>          },

In the result you will see that I highlighted the bookId.  That is what I expect to return when I run it through my controller.

**EDIT**

Database

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('recordId');
            $table->string('bookId');
             $table->integer('userId');
            $table->integer('authorId');
             //$table->integer('genreId');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('isbn');
            $table->binary('description');
            $table->string('preview');
            $table->string('cover');
            $table->string('book_status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        //DB::statement('ALTER TABLE books AUTO_INCREMENT = 2000');
    }
```

Eloquent Model

```php
class book extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'bookId'; 
    protected $fillable = [
        'bookId',
        'userId',
        'authorId',
        'title',
        'isbn',
        'description',
        'preview',
        'cover',
        'book_status'
    ];
    //$guarded = [];
    public function authors(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\author','authorId');
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to clear your cache?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you are looping over the result set and echoing the `bookId` for a single model in the loop. And in tinker, you are retrieving the results and tinker outputs the collection to the console. Doing this in tinker should result the same output as your controller:

```
App\Book::where('userId', 1)->first()->bookId;
```

Again, in tinker, you are retrieving the result set, not a single record, and a lot of additional data, like model details and so on, will be printed in the console. Hope this explanation helps.

Also, you need to correct the typo in your controller. I assume your model name is `Book`, not `book` so you should be using the capital name for the model.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get only one result, you will need the `first()` method from laravel. What that does is, it takes the firs record and shows it to you. This method will not iterate (loop) through your result set.

So your code in Tinker will be like so:

`$books = \App\Book::where('userId',1)->first()->bookId;`

This wil return only the firs results `bookId`.

`Get()` method is used to fetch collections. Collections comes out as arrays. That is why you are getting several bunch of Data's. All of your fields in the table will be displayed and all of your data will be displayed (depending on the options you give like `where('userId', 1)`). That is called a collection. And to iterate or loop through a collection, you will need to use the foreach loop as you have done in your Question.

```
foreach ($books as $b) {
    echo $b->bookId;
}
```

The problem here is that you are echo-ing `$b->bookId`. When you echo in Laravel, it will show you the fields data as a whole number. Like say, if you have bookId 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000 the result will come as `10002000300040005000`. However, if you do something like this in your controller:

```
foreach ($books as $b) {
  echo "<li>" .$b->bookId. "<li>";
}
```

The result will be something like this:

> - 1000
> - 2000
> - 3000
> - 4000
> - 5000

If you want to fetch a single Item's bookId you will do something like this (This example assumes that you know the records 'id'):

`$books = \App\Book::where('userId',1)->find(1)->bookId;`

Now the bookId of result with the id=1 will be displayed.

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I went ahead and added the model as well as the db structure.  I only have one model, that was a mistake on my part, but doesn't change any of my issues.

Comment: Do you want to only get the bookId?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Hope that was what you were looking  for

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help.  However, I was way off base.  The problem is in my Model.  When I changed it around, I meant to change the primary key to be 'recordId', but left it as 'bookId'.
It would appear that Laravel will read that primary key as an integer.  So when I would run the code it would see bookId and think it was primary and then convert it to an integer.  So in reality what was happening was this:

```php
$books = \App\book::where('userId',1)->get();
foreach ($books as $b) {
    //$b->bookid = '7iraCwAAQBAJ'
    echo intval($b->bookId);
    //intval($b->bookId) = 7
}
```

I changed the primary key to 'recordId' and it fixed everything.